# Setting icon for the submenu items in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I had added a new menu item as well as submenu item using the below code. I had succeeded in setting icon for all the submenus(HeatMapAnalysis,Buffer and Intersect.) But I can't set icon for the main submenu "MySubMenu". I tried setting the icon for the same using the code which is in bold below in the code, but no luck.

```
def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/DSGeneric/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Ds Generic'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.custom_menu = QMenu(QCoreApplication.translate("mytool", "Mytool"))
    self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu(self.iface.firstRightStandardMenu().menuAction(), self.custom_menu)
    self.custom_submenu = QMenu(QCoreApplication.translate("mysubmenu", "&MySubMenu"))
    **self.custom_submenu.setIcon(QIcon("/icons/logo_icon.png"))**
    self.custom_add_submenu(self.custom_submenu)

    # Heat Map submenu
    icon = QIcon(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/icons/logo_icon.png")
    self.heat_map_action = QAction(icon, "HeatMapAnalysis", self.iface.mainWindow())
    QObject.connect(self.heat_map_action, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.heatmapAnalysis)
    self.custom_submenu.addAction(self.heat_map_action)
    # Buffer submenu
    icon = QIcon(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/icons/logo_icon.png")
    self.buffer_action = QAction(icon, "Buffer", self.iface.mainWindow())
    QObject.connect(self.buffer_action, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.buffer)
    self.custom_submenu.addAction(self.buffer_action)
    # Intersect submenu
    icon = QIcon(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/icons/logo_icon.png")
    self.intersect_action = QAction(icon, "Intersect", self.iface.mainWindow())
    QObject.connect(self.intersect_action, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.intersect)
    self.custom_submenu.addAction(self.intersect_action)
```

Comment: looks like you're missing the path prefix, which you included with the other ones?

Comment: Yeah silly. But forgot it. Thanks Steven Kay.